# Is there a way to extract nested types from object, based on strings in array in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a typed comparator function with type safety so that I'm sure that I'm always sorting with existing values
So far I have done the following:

```typescript
export enum SortDirection {
    ASCENDING = "ASCENDING",
    DESCENDING = "DESCENDING",
}

/**
 * Sorts in place Array of objects
 * @param path path to numeric value
 * @param direction the way that numeric values will be evaluated
 * @returns the sorted array
 */
export const sortByNumeric = <T>(path: Array<keyof T>, direction = SortDirection.ASCENDING) => <K extends Record<keyof T, any>>(current: K, next: K) => {
    const extractedA = +path.reduce((acc, k) => acc[k], current);
    const extractedB = +path.reduce((acc, k) => acc[k], next);
    return direction === SortDirection.ASCENDING ? extractedA - extractedB : extractedB - extractedA;
}

let source = [
    {
        name: 'Jon',
        age: 20,
        father: {
            name: 'Jon Senior',
            age: 60,
            otherProp: 100
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'Gabriel',
        age: 25,
        father: {
            name: 'Jon Senior',
            age: 80,
            otherProp: 20
        }
    }
];
source.sort(sortByNumeric(['age']));
```

The function is working fine with a single property, but it is not able to work with nested paths like so :

```
source.sort(sortByNumeric(['father' , 'otherProp']));
// Here this will throw an error that the prop doesn't exits, while this is actually a valid property
```

or

```
source.sort(sortByNumeric(['age' , 'father']));
// Here there will be no error, while at the same time this is invalid value as there is no key for the 'father'
```

I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong with the generics, but I have no idea how and what to fix here, any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but not simple to type arbitrarily nested keys. It depends on how exactly you want the type to behave but a possible implementation of such a type would be:

```
export type NumericKeyPath<T> =
    [T] extends [number] ? []
    : [T] extends [object] ? NumericKeyPathProperty<T, keyof T>
    : never;

type NumericKeyPathProperty<T, Key extends keyof T> =
    Key extends (string | number) ? [ Key, ...NumericKeyPath<T[Key]> ]
    : never;

type Test = NumericKeyPath<{ name: string; age: number; father: { name: string; age: number; otherProp: number } }>;
// type Test = ["age"] | ["father", "age"] | ["father", "otherProp"]
```

Used with your comparator function:

```
export const sortByNumeric = <T>(path: NumericKeyPath<T>, direction = SortDirection.ASCENDING) => (current: T, next: T) => {
    // the below casts could be done more precisely 
    const extractedA = +(path as string[]).reduce((acc: any, k) => acc[k], current);
    const extractedB = +(path as string[]).reduce((acc: any, k) => acc[k], next);
    return direction === SortDirection.ASCENDING ? extractedA - extractedB : extractedB - extractedA;
}

let source = [
    {
        name: 'Jon',
        age: 20,
        father: {
            name: 'Jon Senior',
            age: 60,
            otherProp: 100
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'Gabriel',
        age: 25,
        father: {
            name: 'Jon Senior',
            age: 80,
            otherProp: 20
        }
    }
];

source.sort(sortByNumeric(['age']));
// Works

source.sort(sortByNumeric(['father' , 'otherProp']));
// Works

source.sort(sortByNumeric(['age' , 'father']));
// Error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcByBXAtsKBLAYwGlhEAFAQxgAsAeAFQD44BeAKDk7gG16BdOKBjAAdgBMAzjxHYARrgEB%20HnzYBIAFw9%20gkMPFTuEWQCtgBGEvTZchEuSrUyUCCliIGAGjgBrUhAAzOCZ1LRFgADdcAG42NiQUaxx8YlJKGmdXXCQvOHtdfUlffyCmVg4ufKFRIoAKCRh8EQBzOAAfOBkseSgASjhlbjzSbwA6ccxkuzTHBm57PmZVTU7ImLjQSFhBLrgAZWgYABE8KHMYPAgROABvCs4AQT2AYQBRNCOASTQAcVY4ABETzeH2%20PwBnnucCOrxe7y%20v3%20AJhcNBvwhbAAvnEAPQAKjxHDx%200OUjw1zAABsKARUA8oFAKIg4IEWaZzhIiXAAAJgCiMrBwPk0IWOBAQTo2FJwCIUSkYYBc3n8iiCsSnc6Xa40VAAdyZCGoVElUwIMrlCqkurwlMpcHkgll8qowDESrOMAwUBEUh1cAkh1dcH5jMQRJxbE2hzgBCuDX9hwAQohJrYzSw4AxGLVhdQtKmUvZ0nQmN51WcLFr-gdYCcKxcrqNgfCwf0WMxagQvWcRDAtPRvOE9P228w7lw4DicYbUPJKRBdTGKA0pLGMJSxPbUGIrqgsNBUGAK3gJMBKcyobGffAhIyLK6Hv8ANQ5sXL-2NcnNbh8XqjM5iBgtK1LUNIEFoFAiIg3g%20KOwYEAQ3A%20Hw3hdgyogwL0sQTle8a3jSwhiImz6viK74NE036-v%20rpAcAIFgRBUEwXBYFIShqx6FhUIel61zlpqVysCwGY1scGqVo2zZon8yj4feYiPgAtAUd6EcRWjyepcAqVpD6xNibCUsA8ABl6tL-NwULjhOXAiKqwBaAA5AAUlcTmQrZXAUM0jlwAATAADJ5XlwAEji4FoNmhXZDnOW51x7KIlxQB5UIxT5fkAGzBeloUQDqUCZGAWgAIyBYFeWcNiE6YiFnDRbZ9k4M5PwULI%20BnmlGW%20Vo-kAKz1bZ4WFVFVVNXFcCuUJSUiCl3Uxd5vVwAAHLli1cAV1C4MVfWVTFNVcNifCxGwZlQLSowBrA9RJimUqELU3BOZlTm-txU5wAA6tAPicmdEDmcAV2HLdsDJgWj3PSN22pXA3hOVtO0uGAb29B904-VAf1xOdl3XTAYMwBDD0EE9L2%20U58NTTDuBoxjcCvAy0BxEAA)

Note that since it seemed to be the intention of the function, I wrote NumericKeyPath to only permit paths to numeric values. The relevant line is `[T] extends [number] ? []`, for example if you would like to permit string values as well you could change this to `[T] extends [number | string] ? []`.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing sorcery :)